# Tools called trollez and bugez

Tags: salvation

In Peter F. Hamilton's "Salvation" Saga he uses words like "trollez" a lot:

> Like most London streets, Plough Lane had a perpetual swarm of bugez and trollez trundling after their owners, and more of the little vehicles chasing down the central clear path on delivery routes, both legitimate and otherwise.

What are all those *-ez things?

Comment: Reading those 'ez' suffixes really took me out of the story... Most of them just don't roll off the tongue, and I struggle to imagine anyone actually saying them out loud in casual conversation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are semi-autonomous vehicles used for carrying items. The words themselves appear to be a play on "trollies" and "buggies". Trollez seem best suited for travel over flat ground (and are significantly larger). Bugez have "flex wheels" that allow them to climb staircases and can carry suitcases or shopping.

**Trollez**

> Our trollez were all waiting for us in a cluster at the center of the hub: **meter-high pearl-white cylinders with very flexible wheels, carrying all our personal luggage.** Sandjay pinged mine, and it locked on. Of course, Loi had two trollez. All those designer shirts need careful packing.
>
> <sub><sup>[Salvation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34068552-salvation)</sup></sub>

**Bugez**

> ...people cursing each other, parents checking children were keeping up, luggage and shopping bugez being booted as they strove to follow their owners, all of them kicking up a noise to rival a football stadium crowd.
>
> ...
>
> Her apartment was on the second floor, so she ignored the creaky old lift and climbed the stairs, her bugez lumbering along after her.
>
> <sub><sup>[Salvation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34068552-salvation)</sup></sub>

---

The suffix 'ez' seems to indicate that the vehicle or item is self-driving or AI controlled in some fashion. Others include **drudgez** (small roomba-like items that can be used for house cleaning), **bagez** (large holdall type bags on wheels),  **gurnez** (used in hospitals to carry bodies), **loadez** (warehouse operative droids), **servez** (server drones capable of cooking and cleaning), **[deliverez](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbQN-a2d1s0)** (takeaway food delivery vehicles), **boardez** (electric skateboards capable of being folded up into a hand-sized pouch), **carrez** (even smaller semi-autonomous carriers), **taxez** (self-driving carriages with seating, typically for four) and **cabez** (self-motivated rickshaws)

Comment: No wonder they asked the question! The author would have done better to spell them "bugeez" (budgies?) and "trolleez". Otherwise I read them with a short "e", as in "egg".

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/483/)

Comment: My association with the -ez suffixes is with [warez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez), perhaps that is the origin of the style.

Answer (score 6):

From the context of your quote, they're some variation on "buggies" and "trolleys" and seem to be automated. Terms differ depending on the part of the world you live in, but these are both types of small wheeled carts/vehicles for transporting... stuff.

Both [trolleys](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trolley) and [buggies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buggy) can refer to a shopping cart, and a buggy can be a stroller for children while a trolley can be any kid of hand cart/hand truck for transporting boxes or luggage.

Since the story is set in Britain and is written by a British author, one may assume Hamilton had the UK/Commonwealth definitions in mind.

Answer (score 3):

From context in the novel (they're not explicitly described), it's a semi-autonomous trolley; capable of carrying a modest amount of cargo (probably similar to a suitcase or trunk) and following it's owner.